# C/C++: circular shift on matrices

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am trying to write an efficient code to perform circular shift which I need to implement it on multiple times on big matrices during my data processing.

On my first trial, compiler throws some exception and it seems that I may be trying to access matrix element outside its size and I have no idea what is going on wrong.

1) I am also using `Armadillo lib` which has `"mat"` definition.
2) I intend to shift it by row and/ or column.

Here is my try:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "C:\Users\kumar\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\UserLibs\armadillo-3-910-0\include\armadillo"

#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
using namespace arma;



template<class ty>
void circshift(ty *out, const ty *in, int xdim, int ydim, int xshift, int yshift)
{

    int iOutputInd, iInputInd, ii, jj;

    for (int i =0; i < xdim; i++) 
    {
        ii = (i + xshift) % xdim;
        for (int j = 0; j < ydim; j++) 
        {
            jj = (j + yshift) % ydim;

            iOutputInd = ii * ydim + jj;
            iInputInd = i * ydim + j;
            std::cout << " iOutputInd --> " << iOutputInd << " ;  iInputInd -->" << iInputInd << "\n";


            out[iOutputInd] = in[iInputInd]; // EXCEPTION BEING THROWN HERE
        }
    }
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    //a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
    mat a, a_out;   // "mat" defined in C++ lib Armadillo
    a << 1 << 2 << 3 << endr
      << 4 << 5 << 6 << endr
      << 7 << 8 << 9  <<endr;
    a.reshape(3,3);
    //a.print();

    a_out = a;

    int xdim = 3; int ydim = 3; int xshift = 1; int yshift = 0;
    circshift(&a_out, &a, xdim, ydim, xshift, yshift);
    a_out.print();

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine. However, when I try to run, Visual studio throws following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x3FF00000 in Circshift_Example.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation (parameters: 0x00000008).
```

I get another error in visual studio console, which complains:

```
error: Mat::init(): requested size is too large
```

**Update: FINAL SOLUTION** 
I am posting my code as it may be useful for some users.

Please note that I am using "Armadillo" library to create matrix. One can replace Armadillo "mat" class wwith their own matrix class.

**Please up-vote if you use this code.**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "armadillo-3-910-0\include\armadillo"

using namespace arma;


template<class ty>
void circshift(ty& out, const ty& in, int xshift, int yshift)
{
    int iOutputInd, iInputInd, ii, jj;
    int ydim = in.n_cols;
    int xdim = in.n_rows;
    for (int j =0; j < ydim; j++) 
    {
        jj = (j + yshift) % ydim;
        if (jj <0) jj = jj + ydim;
        for (int i = 0; i < xdim; i++) 
        {
            ii = (i + xshift) % xdim;
            if (ii <0) ii = ii + xdim;
            out[jj * xdim + ii] = in[j * xdim + i];
        }
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    //a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
    mat a, a_out;   
    a << 1 << 2 << 3 << endr
      << 4 << 5 << 6 << endr
      << 7 << 8 << 9  <<endr;
    a.reshape(3,3);

    a_out = a;

    int xshift = 1; int yshift = 0;
    circshift(a_out, a, xshift, yshift);
    a_out.print();  

    xshift = 1; yshift = -1;
    circshift(a_out, a, xshift, yshift);
    a_out.print();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do the *compiler* throw an exception? Or do you get compiler *errors*? Or possibly *linker* errors? Or do *your program* throw an exception? And *what* is "thrown"? And *where*?

Comment: **Don't say "I got an error". Always say "Here is the error I got" and then show us the exact error.** Don't paraphrase it. Don't retype it. Cut & paste the error message exactly from your screen.

Comment: "Some exception" ? Where is `mat` definition?

Comment: Oh, and don't retype the code either, copy-and-paste the code you want to show, because then you hopefully will not introduce *new* errors, like you seem to have done with the code shown.

Comment: What is `mat` and what is `Mat` ?

Comment: I don't understand a circular shift for a square matrix.  Are you shifting by columns?  By rows?  By bits?  Spirally?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg My program throws exception and not compiler. It compiles fine. Please see the updated error detail.

Comment: When you used the debugger, did you verify that your array indices do not go out of bounds?

Comment: @EugeneSh. the definition of "mat" in Armadillo library. I have updated my question.

Comment: Where is `Mat::init()` defined?  I didn't see it in any of your posted code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I intend to shift it by column and by row.  The definition of "mat" in Armadillo library. I have updated my question.

Comment: Try using `mat` constructor with the required size, not the default one

Comment: Also, what line of code exactly throws that error?

Comment: @filmor I updated the original question with precise line number and also used std::cout to further investigate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error here is that you pass pointers to `mat` type objects to the `circshift()` function (the `out` and `in` argument, but then use these arguments as arrays to `mat`. The following line is not interpreted as you think

```
out[iOutputInd] = in[iInputInd];
```

because `out` and `in` are not `mat` objects. They are pointers to `mat` objects, so the compiler will interpret `in` and `out` as being pointer to arrays of `mat` and index these arrays, copying a non-existant `mat` from in[...] to another non-existant location.

One simple way to fix that is to use references instead of pointers to pass the `mat` objects, i.e.:

```
template<class ty> void circshift(ty& out, const ty& in, int xdim, int ydim, int xshift, int yshift)
{
    ...
}
```

and call it in _tmain using:

```
circshift(a_out, a, xdim, ydim, xshift, yshift);
```